# CreateFile fails (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) when file has latin characters

Tags: c, file-io, file-not-found, latin

I'm trying to open files in C, but I'm getting problems when the file has latin characters in Windows.

This code

```
hFile = CreateFileW(ws, // file to be opened
GENERIC_READ, // open for reading
FILE_SHARE_READ, // share for reading
NULL, // default security
OPEN_EXISTING, // open existing file only
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL |FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE | SECURITY_IMPERSONATION,
// normal file archive and impersonate client
NULL); // no attr. template

if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    printf("Could not open %ls file, error %d\n", ws, GetLastError());
else
    printf("File's HANDLE is OK!\n");

// when finished, close the file handle
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

works perfectly when the file doesn't have any strange character but fails with error 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) when it does.

--

For example, with this file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\hola.mp3
```

the output is

```
File's HANDLE is OK!
```

But with this file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\holá.mp3
```

the output is

```
Could not open C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\holá.mp3 file, error 2
```

Both files exist on that location.

--

This is the initialisation of ws:

```
char* filename;
wchar_t  ws[256];

// I get the filename from the SDK I am using (Cycling'74 Max SDK)
filename = (atom_getsym(argv))->s_name;
// and convert it to UTF16
AnsiToUnicode16(filename, ws, 256);
```

`AnsiToUnicode16` is using `MultiByteToWideChar` to do the conversion.

--

When I use FindFirstFile() to iterate thru the files of the folder I get this results:

- Next file name is hola.mp3.
- Next file name is hol□.mp3.

I have no idea about how to let it know that `hol□.mp3` should be `holá.mp3`.

BTW, if the folder is the one which has the accent, the FindFirstFile() fails.

Comment: Can you add the output of your programm, and the filename which is problematic?

Comment: Please, how is `ws` defined and initialised?

Comment: Can you create an MCVE? Also, what is `post` and how does it cope with wide characters and `%s`?

Comment: @alk First file contains `Mordaz`, second file contains `Mórdaz`

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, post is the printf of the SDK and %s was wrong, it has to be %ls, corrected now.

Comment: @alk I have changed the filenames so the difference is clear now.

Comment: This is **probably** a Unicode normalization issue. Filenames are normally in NFC but this is not enforced and there can be an NFD file name that looks identical to the corresponding NFC but designates a different file. Do `dir your-directory` and hexdump the output, then compare with the hexdump of your filename as printed by your program.

Comment: *If the folder is the one which has the accent, the FindFirstFile() fails.* Sounds like you are calling `FindFirstFileA`. If so, why do that?

Comment: I have changed to FindFirstFileW and FindNextFileW but I get exactly the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply as Windows tells you. A file with that name does not exist. Whilst you think you got the name right, the system tells you that you did not. The system is correct.

Presumably the result of

```
filename = (atom_getsym(argv))->s_name;
AnsiToUnicode16(filename, ws, 256);
```

does not lead to `ws` having the desired value.

FWIW, `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE` has no impact when opening an existing file, only when creating a file. And `SECURITY_IMPERSONATION` only has effect if you also include `SECURITY_SQOS_PRESENT`.

Comment: But when I print `ws` the value seems correct: `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\Mórdaz -Yo Rockanrolleo.mp3`

Comment: If it was correct then the system would find the file. What I suggest that you do is use `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` to enumerate the contents of the directory until you find the file. And then do a binary comparison of the name from the search record with the value in `ws`.

Comment: Thanks @David Heffman. 
I have successfully done that and when I iterate in that folder I get:
- Next file name is hola.mp3.
- Next file name is hol□.mp3.

This approach fails when the accent is on the folder (like /fólder/file.ext) so it will only solve the problem partially.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve your problem, just answer your question. Really, the file does not exist. Unicode normalization is certainly a possible issue. I suggest that a bigger problem is your use of ANSI. You should stop using ANSI. I know you convert back to UTF-16, but the damage is likely already done by then. And yes, `FindFirstFileW` etc. will reveal the difference. Calling `FindFirstFileA` as it seems you may be doing is no good. Anyway, try to wean yourself off ANSI, it's bad news.

Comment: Heffeman you are absolutely right, the problem was coming from the variable the SDK gave me. I have used a function they provide (charset_utf8tounicode) and now everything is working fine.
Many thanks for your help.